# brew doctor bad interpetor no such file

Tags: macos, homebrew

I haven't tried using brew since upgrading from Mavericks to Yosemite. I'm getting the following error.

```
legion:~ jkratz$ brew doctor
/usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 26: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: Undefined error: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you have anything against running the [uninstaller script](https://gist.github.com/mxcl/1173223) and starting again? Looks like ruby has moved and it can't find it.

Comment: Nope, I'm completely fine with that.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't run `brew upgrade` in a while and Apple upgraded their Ruby!

To fix, do `cd /usr/local && git pull` and you should be fine.